# v-data-table parent item data in expanded-item slot

Tags: vue.js, nested-table, v-data-table

I've a v-data-table inside the expanded-item slot for another data table. I want to access the ID of the parent item within the child. I've tested with a

inside the expanded-item slot, in that paragraph, I am able to show the id. However, inside the child data-table, I don't know how to use this value.

```
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="financialDocuments"
      :single-expand="singleExpand"
      item-key="finDocId"
      show-expand
    >
      <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
        <td :colspan="attachmentHeaders.length">
          <p>{{item.finDocId}}</p>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="attachmentHeaders"
            :items="item.attachmentPlainDtos"
          >
            <template v-slot:[`item.attachmentActions`]="{ item }">
              <v-icon large @click="removeAttachment(parentItem.Id, item.attachmentId)">
                mdi-delete
              </v-icon>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </td>            
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Comment: What is the value of "attachmentActions" ?

Comment: @NehaSoni its the name of the column within the expanded-item table.

Answer (score 0):

The parent item was already available, just had to rename the reference to it to prevent two "item"s, one is the parent, one is child and refer to the correct one.

```
    <v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="financialDocuments"
  :single-expand="singleExpand"
  item-key="finDocId"
  show-expand
>
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item: finDoc }">
    <td :colspan="attachmentHeaders.length">
      <v-data-table
        :headers="attachmentHeaders"
        :items="finDoc.attachmentPlainDtos"
      >
        <template v-slot:[`item.attachmentActions`]="{ item }">
          <v-icon large @click="removeAttachment(finDoc.Id, item.attachmentId)">
            mdi-delete
          </v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </td>            
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```